# Is $[0,1]$ the union of $2^{\aleph_0}$ perfect sets which are pairwise disjoint?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

I need represent [0,1] as the union of $2^{\aleph_0}$ perfect sets which are pairwise disjoint.

I have thought about removing open disjoint sets but the number of open sets I get is countable. Thanks.

Comment: As $C$ (the Cantor set) is homeomorphic to $C \times C$ (e.g. because both are homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$) we can already write the Cantor set as such a union.

Comment: hmm but I need to write [0,1], not $C$.

Comment: There are indeed only countable families of disjoint open subsets (in a separable metric space..)

Comment: Does your definition of perfect include closed? so $P' = P$ iff $P$ is perfect?

Comment: Can we assume the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @bof I for one would like to see a construction using the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @coffeemath Use transfinite induction. Assuming CH (or more generally that the union of $\lt2^{\aleph_0}$ meager sets is meager) all you need is that, given countably many nowhere dense perfect sets $P_1,P_2,\dots$ and a point $x\in\mathbb R\setminus(P_1\cup P_2\cup\cdots),$ you can find a nowhere dense perfect set $P$ such that $x\in P\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus(P_1\cup P_2\cup\cdots).$

Comment: When you write "perfect" do you mean perfect and closed?

Comment: Henno  and Carl yes, closed and dense in itself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, one can do this. The idea is to take a suitable space-filling curve $f: [0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ and take as the partition of $I$ the preimages of, say, vertical lines under $f$. The preimages will be clearly compact, disjoint, but one needs to work (by taking a suitable function $f$) to ensure their perfectness. For the details, see:

Edgar A. Cohen Jr., *[A Solution of a Problem of I. P. Natanson Concerning the Decomposition of an Interval into Disjoint Perfect Sets](http://file.scirp.org/pdf/APM_2014051216021868.pdf)*, Advances in Pure Mathematics, Vol.4 (2014) No.5, 189-193.

Comment: The "usual example" of the Peano curve$ f:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ has the property that $f(\;[(j-1)4^{-n},j4^{-n}]\;)=[a2^{-n},(a+1)2^{-n}]\times [b2^{-n}, (b+1)2^{-n}]$  for some integers $a,b$ whenever $ n,j\in \mathbb Z^+$ with $j\leq 4^n.$........ From this we can readiily show that if $f(x)=(u,v)$ and if  $V$ is any nbhd of x, then there exists $y\in V$ with $f(x)\ne f(y)\in \{u\}\times [0,1] .$..... So $x$ is not an isolated point of $f^{-1}(\{u\}\times [0,1]).$....................+1.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, that was my first thought as well, but instead of proving it myself I looked for a reference; I did not check the published proof to see if there are some subtleties .

Comment: I should have thought of this solution (but I didn't) because the composite $pf$ where $p$ is the projection of $[0,1]^2$ to the first co-ordinate, is  one of my favorite functions. The function $pf$ is continuous and nowhere-differentiable and if $V$ is a nbhd of $x\in [0,1]$ then the cardinal of  $V\cap (pf)^{-1}\{pf(x)\}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I had the same idea and encountered the same perfectness problem, demanding investigation of the curve structure, so I have searched a [suitable space-filling curve]. My last try was [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Peano_curve) curve.

Comment: It fills a triangle instead of a square, but its filling pattern looks for me more easy to deal than that of the [other space-filling curves](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000003494/2_kap2.pdf), because at each next step of the construction we only split each of the triangles from the previous step into two. It looks promising to take as the partition the preimages of the horizontals segments, but the preimages of the square grid vertices need careful inspection for the perfectness.

Comment: Also the topmost segment is a singleton, but this can be fixed by considering instead it a triangle with the same vertex and opposite horizontal side, because there still remains $2^{\aleph_0}$ sets in the partition.

Comment: But, anyway, you was the first and your answer is complete, so I upvoted it.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Dear Alex, by all means if you find an alternative, post it.